# How to use gulp-load-plugins with TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, gulp, gulp-load-plugins

I found no examples for `gulp-load-plugins` in TypeScript. Unfortunately,
my TypeScript is too poor to understand, what should to do from **@type/gulp-load-plugins**
comments.

I tried:

```
import * as _gulpPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
const gulpPlugins: IGulpPlugins = _gulpPlugins();

return gulp.src(sourceFilesGlobSelections)
        .pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())
        // ...
```

It makes 4 warnings from Webpack (I dont understand where number such `75:13-25` refers; `.pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())` is on 50 row):

```
WARNING in ../node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js 75:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./TaskManagers/MarkupPreprocessingHelper.ts

WARNING in ../node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js 81:48-63
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./TaskManagers/MarkupPreprocessingHelper.ts

WARNING in ../node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js 117:40-55
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./TaskManagers/MarkupPreprocessingHelper.ts

WARNING in ../node_modules/gulp-load-plugins/index.js 122:51-66
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./TaskManagers/MarkupPreprocessingHelper.ts
```

It was told in `@types/gulp-load-plugins`:

```
/**
 * Extend this interface to use Gulp plugins in your gulpfile.js
 */
interface IGulpPlugins {
}
```

I tried:

```
interface IGulpPlugins {
  pug: () => NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
}
```

It also defined:

```
declare module 'gulp-load-plugins' {

    interface IOptions {
        // ...
    }

    interface IPluginNameMappings {
        [npmPackageName: string]: string
    }

    /** Loads in any gulp plugins and attaches them to an object, freeing you up from having to manually require each gulp plugin. */
    function gulpLoadPlugins<T extends IGulpPlugins>(options?: IOptions): T;

    // ...
}
```

It looks like maybe I should use `gulpLoadPlugins` instead of interface extending ...
Is is all that I understand with my current TypeScirpt proficiency, but it not enough to understand how to use `gulp-load-plugins` in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is the working example in [gulp-load-plugins-tests.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gulp-load-plugins/gulp-load-plugins-tests.ts):

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');
import gulpLoadPlugins = require('gulp-load-plugins');

interface GulpPlugins extends IGulpPlugins {
    concat: typeof gulpConcat;
}

gulp.task('taskName', () => {
    gulp.src('*.*')
        .pipe(plugins.concat('concatenated.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
});
```

About `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`: do not bundle Node.js dependencies for the webpack projects those target is Node.js (not browser). [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) will tell webpack do not bundle Node.js libraries, however it's still possible to import and use them as usual.